# My Windows 7 automatically disables USB- devices (Code 22)

Tags: windows-7, usb

When I right click on device and hit enable, the device gets enabled for a few seconds and automatically disables again. I have tried to set

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USBSTOR]
"Start"=dword:00000003
```

But still nothing. Is there any way to bypass this auto disabling of usb devices?

Comment: Are you using a Local profile or a Domain profile.

Comment: not sure about that.

Comment: Determine that information and update your question.

Comment: @Ramhound It is a Local Profile

Comment: What does value on the following group policy Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Custom Policy Settings -> Write Protection

Comment: There is no "Custom Policy Settings" under my Administrative Templates

Comment: Are you able to find any mention of `Write Protection` else where in the policy?  This Local profile is a `User` or `Administrator`?